# Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable in SettingView

Tags: swiftui

I am creating a page settingView for saving userdata where I call a class with @ObservedObject.
And I also made some func in the settingView page for load and save the userdata.
But there I get the error "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable in SettingView". How can I solve this.

```
class UserData: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var name = ""
    @Published var firstname = ""
    @Published var email = ""
}

struct SettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var userdata = UserData()

var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView{
            Form {
                Section(header: Text("User")){
                    TextField("Name", text: $userdata.name)
                    TextField("Firstname", text: $userdata.firstname)
                    TextField("Email...", text: $userdata.email)
                   //more code
                }
                Section{
                    Button(action: {
                        self.saveData()
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    }){
                        Text("Save")
                    }
            }
        }

        .onAppear(perform: {
            self.loadData()
        })
    }
    
    func getDocumentsDirectory() -> URL {
        let paths = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
        return paths[0]
    }
    
    func loadData() {
        let filename = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent("SavedData")

        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: filename)
            userdata = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserData.self, from: data) <-- error on userdata
            print("File is loaded")
        } catch {
            print("Unable to load saved data.")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot assign to an ObservedObject. An ObservableObject is an object that modifies *itself*, and when it does, it notifies observes. So typically you would implement this as `userData.load(from: filename)` and letting UserData do all the work, rather than reassigning `userData`. To make that work properly, you'll need to wrap up the struct that you're decoding (it can't replace itself). So your ObservableObject would likely be something like "DataStore" that *holds* a UserData.

Comment: So you saying that I must make a extra func for the DataStore from UserData to userdata?

Comment: I'm saying that if you want an ObservableObject, it should be a persistent (not replaced) object that you observe and that has `@Published` properties for all of the things you want to observe. You can implement that many ways. One would be to load a single UserData object and expose it as `@Published`.

Comment: @DixitAkabari As in the other case where you added this link, it is not applicable to the question. SettingsView is a SwiftUI View and cannot be made into a class. Please stop posting this link as comments on unrelated questions.